# group() query, finalise clause, Can I show a sub-querying example?

Tags: mongodb, subquery, mongodb-query

Sub querying in mongoDB is non-sense. But what is this guy doing here?

Summarizing:

> 1. he queries the **links** collection;
> 2. looking at the finalize clause, he queries the **users** collection.

I can't do that, keep getting an error msg:

```
uncaught exception: group command failed: {
"errmsg" : "exception: ReferenceError: db is not defined
at $finalize ($group finalize define:2:22)    
at _funcs2 (_funcs2:1:73) at $group finalize define:2",
"code" : 16722,
"ok" : 0
```

}

I am not an expert, is it possible?

[image: Where my issue begins]